# Java SLF4J hierachy execution

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

There's any way to execute every log in the hierachy from a particular son?

**For example:**

```
-Parent
    -Son
       -Son2
```

1. Executing Son.log("message") would execute Son log and Parent log.
2. Executing Son2.log("message") would execute Son2, Son and parent log.

That's the code:

```
public class HelloWorld {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       Logger parent = LoggerFactory.getLogger("parent");
       ((ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) parent).setLevel(Level.DEBUG);

       Logger son= LoggerFactory.getLogger("parent.son");
       son.debug("hello");
   }
}
```

Output:

`14:15:25.180 [main] DEBUG logger.son- Hello world.`

Desired Output:

`14:15:25.180 [main] DEBUG parent.son- Hello world.
14:15:25.180 [main] DEBUG parent- Hello world.`

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by executing every log in the hierarchy?

Comment: I mean: execute method log on son1 forces to execute son1.log() and parent.log(), because parent is on son1 hierachy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how it works. SLF4J Logger hierarchy cannot be used (and should not be) in the way you want.

Basically, for each logger, if you don't define any setting, the settings will be copied from the parent. In your hierarchy, the logging level is set to `DEFAULT` for `parent` and nothing is defined for `parent.son`. So the logging level for `parent.son` will also be `DEBUG`. So all the logs with level higher than or equal to `DEBUG` will be logged for `parent.son`. If you set log level to `TRACE` for the son, then that will take precedence over parent's DEBUG level.

Comment: Then I can't see what are the benefits of that hierachy if you only can copy settings from parent and can't execute anything else.

Comment: Why do you want to have same log message to be repeated over and over?

Comment: I misunderstood it, I'm sorry. If son inherits the parent appender it's like "executing the parent logger function". Thanks.